# Get App Member Username on Webview (POST Method)

Tags: android, post, webview, android-webview

Here is my Problem on my Webview.
I have created a Webview activity in my android app user Dashboard.
Now I need to output the logged-in member username on my `php` page.

Here is my Code
maybe anyone can help and find my bug
I'm using Android Studio

Android Activity Code:

```
public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cpa);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.org/page.php?username="+App.getInstance().getUsername());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Here is my `php` Page:

```
<?php
include_once 'connect_database.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];

?>

<html>


<body>
<?php echo $username ?>
</body>
```